Unable to access Public APIs using request library in EMR serverless
Getting below error when I am trying to fetch a API using request library.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/spark-39775710-130a-4403-9182-c557003f351b/lib.zip/urllib3/connection.py", line 196, in _new_conn
  File "/tmp/spark-39775710-130a-4403-9182-c557003f351b/lib.zip/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
  File "/tmp/spark-39775710-130a-4403-9182-c557003f351b/lib.zip/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/spark-39775710-130a-4403-9182-c557003f351b/lib.zip/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 789, in urlopen
  File "/tmp/spark-39775710-130a-4403-9182-c557003f351b/lib.zip/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 490, in _make_request
  File "/tmp/spark-39775710-130a-4403-9182-c557003f351b/lib.zip/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 466, in _make_request
  File "/tmp/spark-39775710-130a-4403-9182-c557003f351b/lib.zip/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1095, in _validate_conn
  File "/tmp/spark-39775710-130a-4403-9182-c557003f351b/lib.zip/urllib3/connection.py", line 615, in connect
  File "/tmp/spark-39775710-130a-4403-9182-c557003f351b/lib.zip/urllib3/connection.py", line 211, in _new_conn
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0xffff812d8a60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/spark-39775710-130a-4403-9182-c557003f351b/lib.zip/requests/adapters.py", line 667, in send
  File "/tmp/spark-39775710-130a-4403-9182-c557003f351b/lib.zip/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 843, in urlopen
  File "/tmp/spark-39775710-130a-4403-9182-c557003f351b/lib.zip/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 519, in increment
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/vehicles/getallmakes?format=json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0xffff812d8a60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/spark-39775710-130a-4403-9182-c557003f351b/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
  File "/tmp/spark-39775710-130a-4403-9182-c557003f351b/lib.zip/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
  File "/tmp/spark-39775710-130a-4403-9182-c557003f351b/lib.zip/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
  File "/tmp/spark-39775710-130a-4403-9182-c557003f351b/lib.zip/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
  File "/tmp/spark-39775710-130a-4403-9182-c557003f351b/lib.zip/requests/adapters.py", line 700, in send
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/vehicles/getallmakes?format=json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0xffff812d8a60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))

Code that I have
import requests
def call_api():
    url = "https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/getallmakes?format=json"
    
    payload = {}
    headers = {}
    
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    
    print(response.text)

Same code is working in AWS Lambda and even in my local, don't know what's wrong in EMR serverless.
Note: I am not using any VPC or subnets configs

The request times out, so the packets are probably getting dropped.
It does not look like the server is dropping anything (since it works on AWS Lambda and your local. The url also works from my side).
So I think there is a firewall in EMR serverless dropping the packets.
Steps to solve:

Check your firewall and network config on EMR
try to access other urls from EMR: can you fetch google? ping your own computer? do the packets get dropped when going to the server or when coming back ? This should help with the debugging


I am not able to access any other public APIs as well from emr serverless and surprisingly there is no VPC configured for emr so I am surprised and clueless what's going wrong

definitely a network thing then, probably firewall. Check your configs for the network stack? probably look at this tutorial for example
